# I'm unable, for some reason, to create GLFW context

Tags: c++, glfw, glew

I'm currently writing a 3D engine using GLFW & GLEW (previously glad). But when calling glfwMakeContextCurrent, it fails. It is the first time I encounter this error, since glad didn't require any calls to init functions.

I searched for possible solutions, but none of them seem to work for me. But, when i tried using code from [this](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer.php?code=getting-started/hellotriangle) tutorial, really close to my code - really close to my code tutorial, it all worked as expected.

So, my questions is:
      How to somehow fix the GLFW problem?

Main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>


#include "Engine3.h"


void UserCreate() {}
void UserUpdate(float ElapsedTime) {}

static void UserCursorEvent(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos) { }

static void UserMouseButtonEvent(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mods) { }

static void UserKeyEvent(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) { }

int main(void) {



    ENGINE e;

    e.AppTitle = "Game";

    if (e.Init(800, 600, ENGINE3_WINDOWED))
    {
        e.UserCreationCallback = &UserCreate;
        e.UserUpdateCallback = &UserUpdate;

        e.SetKeyCallback(&UserKeyEvent);
        e.SetCursorCallback(&UserCursorEvent);
        e.SetMouseCallback(&UserMouseButtonEvent);

        e.Begin();
    }
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Engine3.h:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <iostream>


#define GLEW_STATIC
#include<GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>


#define ENGINE3_WINDOWED 0
#define ENGINE3_FULLSCREEN 1

#define Log(msg) std::cout << msg << std::endl;
#define _IN_
#define _OUT_

class ENGINE {


public:

    //Creates window of size [x,y] on primary monitor
    bool Init(_IN_ int Width, 
              _IN_ int Height, 
              _IN_ int Mode);  

    //Inits OpenGL and starts the engine
    void Begin();

    void (*UserCreationCallback)(),
         (*UserUpdateCallback)(_OUT_ float ElapsedTime),
         (*UserDestructionCallback)();

    //Sets callback for keyboard events
    void SetKeyCallback(_IN_ GLFWkeyfun KeyFun);

    //Sets callback for cursor position update 
    void SetCursorCallback(_IN_ GLFWcursorposfun CursorFun);

    //Sets callback for mouse click events
    void SetMouseCallback(_IN_ GLFWmousebuttonfun MouseFun);


    const char* AppTitle = nullptr;
    GLFWwindow* Window = nullptr;

private:
    void MainLoop();     
};
```

Engine3.cpp:

```cpp
#include "Engine3.h"

bool ENGINE::Init(int width, int height, int mode)
{
#ifdef  GLEW_MX 
    #undef GLEW_MX 
#endif //  GLEW_MX 


    if (!glfwInit()) {
        Log("ERROR::GLFW::INIT_ERROR"); 
        return false; //If the GLFW init failed, there's no need to terminate it
    }

    GLFWwindow* window = nullptr;
    const GLFWvidmode* currentVidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor()); //Retrive video mode from primary monitor

    //Some hints to ensure compatibility
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RED_BITS, currentVidmode->redBits); //Set depth of R chanel to value of a monitor
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_GREEN_BITS, currentVidmode->greenBits); //Set depth of G chanel to value of a monitor
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_BLUE_BITS, currentVidmode->blueBits); //Set depth of B chanel to value of a monitor
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_REFRESH_RATE, currentVidmode->refreshRate); //Set refresh rate to value of a monitor
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE); //Make, so window couldn't be resized by user
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4); //Set minimum required version of OpenGL to 4.0
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0); 
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); //Just for safety, 'cause there's no need to use old legacy stuff

    //Check, what mode is used and act accordingly
    if (mode == ENGINE3_FULLSCREEN)
        window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, ENGINE::AppTitle, glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), NULL); 
    else if(mode == ENGINE3_WINDOWED)
        window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, ENGINE::AppTitle, NULL, NULL); 

    if (!window) {
        Log("ERROR::GLFW::WINDOW_OPENING_ERROR"); //Throw an error
        glfwTerminate(); //But if the window could't be opened, GLFW must be terminated
        return false;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(ENGINE::Window); //Activate window
    ENGINE::Window = window; //Save window for later use

    if (!glfwGetCurrentContext()) {
        Log("ERROR::GLFW::UNABLE_TO_CREATE_CONTEXT");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void ENGINE::Begin()
{
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if (GLenum err = (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)) { 
        Log("ERROR::GLEW::UNABLE_TO_INIT" << std::endl << glewGetErrorString(err));
        return; 
    }

    ENGINE::UserCreationCallback();

    GLsizei winSizeX, winSizeY;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(ENGINE::Window, &winSizeX, &winSizeY);
    glViewport(0, 0, winSizeX, winSizeY);


    ENGINE::MainLoop();

    glfwTerminate();
}




void ENGINE::MainLoop() 
{

    float prevFrameTime = .0f;
    GLint RendererSetupSuccess = 1;

    if (!ENGINE::renderer.InitRenderer()){
        Log("ERROR::RENDERER::INIT_ERROR");
        return;
    }
    ENGINE::renderer = renderer;


    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(ENGINE::Window))
    {
        GLfloat currenTtime = (GLfloat)glfwGetTime();
        GLfloat elapsed = currenTtime - prevFrameTime;
        prevFrameTime = currenTtime;


        Log("Update");      
        glfwPollEvents();
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSwapBuffers(ENGINE::Window);
    }
}
```

Every time I run the program, it throws the 'ERROR::GLFW::UNABLE_TO_CREATE_CONTEXT' error. I don't know what's happening.
For any help, thanks.

Comment: That error message you are getting is produced by your own code, so it's hard to tell what's going on unless you read and output the underlying error code or message from the GLFW library. I'm not familiar with that library, but search the API documentation for a function that gives you the most recent error code or error message. Also take a look at the following documentation page: https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/group__error.html

Comment: Not sure but you only appear to assign a non-null value to `ENGINE::Window` immediately *after* you've passed it to `glfwMakeContextCurrent`.

Comment: In these cases (where you find a similar piece of code that works), start from that and gradually change it to your program in order to find when it breaks. This can help you pinpoint the error more accurately

Answer (score 1):

You are using `ENGINE::Window`, before it was assigned; so it's `NULL`. That is the reason (I think) the  `glfwMakeContextCurrent` function fails.

Use:

```
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
```

Instead of:

```
glfwMakeContextCurrent(ENGINE::Window);
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
glfwMakeContextCurrent(ENGINE::Window); //Activate window
ENGINE::Window = window; //Save window for later use
```

`ENGINE::Window` is still a nullptr, so you are just passing a nullptr to the glfwContext creation. Either change the order, or use `glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); // the local variable`